# connecting PayPal payment on C# Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, paypal, blazor

I'm trying to connect PayPal to the service, but it doesn't work and a table with items added to card for the further payment isn't showing on the page.
There is no transition to the service page for payment using the test bank card.

here is my project:

https://github.com/SashaMaksyutenko/ShopOnline

This code - table which must be shown when I make payment for items which I want to buy.

```
@page "/CheckOut"
    @inherits CheckOutBase
    <h3 class="mb-5">CheckOut</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="display:@DisplayButtons">
            <h4 class="mb-2">Payment Method</h4>
            <div id="smart-button-container">
                <input type="hidden" name="descriptionInput" id="description" @bind="PaymentDescription" />
                <input name="amountInput" type="hidden" id="amount" @bind="PaymentAmount">
                <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0.625rem;" id="paypal-button-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        @if (ShoppingCartItems == null)
        {
            <DisplaySpinner />
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4 class="mb-2">Payment Summary</h4>
                @if (ShoppingCartItems.Count()>0)
                    {
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach(var item in ShoppingCartItems)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@item.Qty x @item.ProductName</td>
                                <td>@item.TotalPrice.ToString("C")</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Total</b></td>
                                    <td><b>@PaymentAmount.ToString("C")</b></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You currently have no Items in your ShoppingCart</p>
                    }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what is your issue, what do you expect to have that you do not have. I don't see any code specific to Paypal.

Comment: this is code. for reflection all items on the page wich where added to card